# Ciclo do while que se repite de manera infinita

Tags: java, array, bucles

Se me planteo el siguiente ejercicio:

> 1. Elaborar el código necesario para que se muestre el siguiente menú de acciones:
>
>    ```
>    MENU
>
>    1 - Ingresar nuevo producto.
>
>    2 – Eliminar producto.
>
>    3- Imprimir listado
>
>    4 -  Salir.
>    ```
> 2. Definir una función llamada AltaProducto, que permita al usuario ingresar un nuevo producto al arreglo. El ID del elemento es el índice en el arreglo. Validar que el ID del elemento sea válido para que no provoque  el error fuera de índice (función “ValidarIndice”). (Máximo 50 productos)
> 3. Definir una función llamada EliminarProducto, que permita al usuario eliminar un producto. El ID del elemento es el índice en el arreglo. Validar que el ID del elemento sea válido para que no provoque  el error fuera de índice (función “ValidarIndice”).
> 4. Definir función “ValidarIndice” y llamarla cuando se da de alta o cuando se eliminar un producto.
> 5. Crear una función para imprimir todos los productos cargados junto con sus índices.  (Si no hay productos cargados, no imprimirlos directamente)

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Opcion, AltaProducto, ValidarIndice, EliminarProducto;
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de productos que desea (limite 50 productos): ");
        ValidarIndice = reader.nextInt();

        char[] producto = new char [ValidarIndice];
        System.out.println("Ingrese los productos: ");
        for(int i=0; i<ValidarIndice;i++){
            System.out.println((i+0)+ ". numero del producto: ");
            producto [i] = reader.next().charAt(0); 
        }
        
        System.out.println("MENU. \n1.Ingresar nuevo producto. \n2.Eliminar producto. \n3.Implimir listado. \n4.Salir.");
        Opcion = reader.nextInt();


        do{
        switch(Opcion){
            case 1: System.out.println("Ingrese Id del producto: ");
            AltaProducto = reader.nextInt();
            if(AltaProducto>ValidarIndice){
                System.out.println("El Id ingresado es erroneo, intente otra Id");
            }

            else if (AltaProducto<=ValidarIndice){
                System.out.println("El nuevo valor de este producto es:"+ AltaProducto);
            break;
            }    

            case 2: System.out.println("Ingrese Id del producto a eliminar: ");
            EliminarProducto = reader.nextInt();
            if(EliminarProducto>ValidarIndice){
                System.out.println("El Id ingresado es erroneo, intente otra Id");
            break;

            }
            else if(EliminarProducto<=ValidarIndice){
                ValidarIndice = 0;
             break;
            }
            case 3: System.out.println("Los productos son: ");
            for(int i=0; i<ValidarIndice;i++){
                System.out.println(producto[i]);
             break;  
            }
            case 4: System.out.println("Gracias por utilizar este programa, hasta luego.");
            break;

            default: System.out.println("El comando ingresado no existe, intente nuevamente.");
            break;
            
     }       }while(Opcion!=4);
    

       reader.close();
    }
}
```

De esa manera lo resolví, pero tiende a caer en un bucle infinito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios errores en tu codigo como lo señalado en el comentario de los breaks dentro de los if y for, estos break deben ser la ultima linea de cada uno de tus cases. Realicé una implementación sencilla basándome en tu código, espero te sea de utilidad.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Opcion, productoId;
        String producto;
        
        int cantidadMaxProductos = 50;
        String[] productos = new String[cantidadMaxProductos];
        int contadorProductos = 0;
        
        do{
            System.out.println("MENU. \n1.Ingresar nuevo producto. \n2.Eliminar producto. \n3.Imprimir listado de productos. \n4.Salir.");
            Opcion = reader.nextInt();
            switch(Opcion){
                case 1: 
                    System.out.println("Ingrese un producto: ");
                    producto = reader.next();
                    if(contadorProductos <= cantidadMaxProductos){
                         productos[contadorProductos++] = producto;
                         System.out.println("Producto " + producto + " agregado correctamente." );
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Haz sobrepasado la cantidad de " + cantidadMaxProductos + " permitida.");
                    } 
                break;
                case 2: 
                    System.out.println("Ingrese Id del producto a eliminar: ");
                    productoId = reader.nextInt();
                    if(productoId <= contadorProductos ){
                       productos[productoId] = null;
                       System.out.println("El id de producto fue eliminado.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("El id de producto ingresado no existe.");
                    }
                break;
                case 3: 
                    System.out.println("Los productos son: ");
                    for(int i=0; i<contadorProductos;i++){
                        if(productos[i] != null) {
                            System.out.println(productos[i] + " id[" + i + "]");
                        }
                    }
                break; 
                case 4: 
                    System.out.println("Gracias por utilizar este programa, hasta luego.");
                break;
                default: 
                    System.out.println("El comando ingresado no existe, intente nuevamente.");
            }       
            
        } while(Opcion!=4);
           reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Francisco, me sirvió mucho de verdad, gracias por tomarte el tiempo para ayudarme.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya sido de ayuda, si puedes coloca mi respuesta como correcta

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que solo le pides una vez al usuario que ingrese la opción deseada. Lo único que tienes que hacer es pedirlo en cada iteración del ciclo. Así:

```
do {
    Opcion = reader.nextInt();
    ...
} while (Opcion != 4);
```

En cuanto a la opción 3, no está funcionando como esperarías porque dejaste el break del switch dentro del ciclo y lo corta. La solución es moverlo fuera.

```
for(int i=0; i<ValidarIndice;i++){
    System.out.println(producto[i]);
}
break;
```

Comment: gracias eso lo corregi y si funciona, ahora, como hago corrigo la parte del case 3, para que me muestra en pantalla todo el array?